# VBA How change row color and add text to cell?

Tags: vba

Sub Accept()
Sheets("Deliver").Select

Dim inputID As String

inputID = InputBox("Enter order ID")

Dim orderID As Range

Set orderID = Range("B:B").Find(what:=inputID, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlPart)

If Not orderID Is Nothing Then

```
orderID.Offset(0, 6).Interior.Color = vbGreen
```

> I want to change the row in green

```
orderID.Offset(0, 6).Vaule = "Delivering"
```

> I want to add text "Delivering" in the cell moved to the right by 6.

End If

End Sub

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code? In the VBA editor, press F8 repeatedly and it will do it one line at a time - you can then see which line isn't working correctly.

Comment: Your code works well for me. Try changing `xlWhole` to `xlPart`. If this works, that means you have some invisible characters in that column (e.g. leading/trailing spaces).

Comment: @SuperSymmetry  I have edited the problem. new problem occurs

Comment: @SpencerBarnes I have edited the problem. new problem occurs

Comment: Please do not change the question. You can update the question for clarifications. But you cannot just change it to a different one. If you have a different question then ask it in a separate post. Furthermore, you say "new problem occurs". Are people supposed to guess what the problem is? Kindly read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update your post appropriately.